# Why is the function insertAtEnd giving me Segmentation Fault in my code for LinkedLists?

Tags: linked-list, segmentation-fault

I'm learning Insertion in a LinkedLists and I tried to code it out. I have coded out many different functions like insertAtBegin (which inserts a new node in the beginning), insertAtIndex (which inserts a new node at a particular index).

I wrote the following code for insertAtEnd(which adds a node at the end of the linked-list) but it is giving me some errors.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Node
{
    int value;
    struct Node *nextPtr;
};

void printValue(struct Node *ptr)
{
    while (ptr != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d\n", ptr->value);
        ptr = ptr->nextPtr;
    }
}

struct Node* insertAtBegin(struct Node* head, int value)
{
    struct Node *new;
    new=(struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    new->nextPtr=head;
    new->value=value;
    return new;
}

void insertAtIndex(struct Node* head, int index, int value) //Index starts from 0. Beginning (before head is )
{
    struct Node* p=head;
    for(int i=1; i<=index-1; i++)
    {
        p=p->nextPtr;
    }
    
    struct Node *ptr;
    ptr=(struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    ptr->nextPtr=p->nextPtr;
    ptr->value=value;
    p->nextPtr=ptr;
}

void insertAtEnd(struct Node* head, int value)
{
    struct Node* q;
    q=head;
    while(q!=NULL)
        q=q->nextPtr;
    
    struct Node *ptr2;
    ptr2=(struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    ptr2->nextPtr=NULL;
    ptr2->value=value;
    q->nextPtr=ptr2;
}

int main()
{
    //Creating pointers to nodes
    struct Node *head;
    struct Node *first;
    struct Node *second;

    //Creating a node by allocating it memeory by malloc
    head = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node)); //A malloc allocates contiguous blocks of main memory
    first = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    second = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));

    //adding value
    head->value=1;
    first->value=2;
    second->value=3;

    //linking nodes
    head->nextPtr=first;
    first->nextPtr=second;
    second->nextPtr=NULL;

    //Test for insertAtBegin
    int value1=0;
    head=insertAtBegin(head, value1);

    //Test for insertAtIndex
    insertAtIndex(head, 3, 4);

    //Test for insertAtEnd
    insertAtEnd(head, 5);

    printValue(head);
    return 0;
}
```

For some reason, the function insertAtEnd is giving me Segmentation Fault. Commenting it doesn't give me any error.

I do not understand why is it giving me such an error, where am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the function `insertAtEnd()`-

```
while(q!=NULL) 
    q=q->nextPtr;
```

At the end of the while loop, pointer `q` is `NULL` (which is why the while loop terminated in the first place), so the line -

```
q->nextPtr=ptr2;
```

is trying to access `nextPtr` of a non-existing struct Node(`NULL`) which is what leads to the segmentation fault.

A simple fix is to stop the while loop before `q` becomes `NULL` by iterating over the condition that `q->nextPtr` is not `NULL`.

```
while(q->nextPtr!=NULL) 
    q=q->nextPtr;
```

So at the end of the loop, `q` points to the last element of the linked list and the line `q->nextPtr=ptr2;` modifies the `nextPtr` of the last node.